# Nodes from XML query instead of variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xmlnode

```
<UserSettings>
   <ActiveStaff>
    <int>2063</int>
    <int>2062</int>
    <int>5</int>
    <int>10</int>
    <int>2064</int>
   </ActiveStaff>
</UserSettings>
```

This is the XML I have, it's part of a varchar column. In MS SQL if I declare an XML variable, set it to some XML (column User.Settings is varchar so it is cast to XML) and then use nodes on it it provides a 5 columns with the values I need.

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml= (SELECT CAST(CAST(User.Settings AS NTEXT) AS XML) from User where User_id = 3)

SELECT T.c.query('.').value('.','int')   
FROM @xml.nodes('//UserSettings/ActiveStaff/int') T(c)
```

However, if I try to skip the variable and use a query.nodes, it cannot be executed:

```
SELECT T.c.query('.').value('.','int')   
FROM (SELECT CAST(CAST(User.Settings AS NTEXT) AS XML) from User where User_id = 
3).nodes('//UserSettings/ActiveStaff/int') T(c)
```

Is there a way to bypass using variables and use a query instead? I need this because later I need to query the XML in a where condition, and I cannot create any extra tables. Any alternative approaches to query a XML string in a column are also welcomed

Comment: Why are you casting to `ntext` here? The data type have been deprecated for *17 years*. Also `from user` is going to cause an incorrect syntax near keyword 'user' error.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

You need to `CROSS APPLY` to the `nodes` column. Your derived table will return a dataset, not `xml`, and the `nodes` method is specific to the `xml` datatype:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #YourTable (User_id int,Settings xml); --I assume your XML data is in an XML data type, right? Why wouldn't it be?
INSERT INTO #YourTable (User_id,Settings)
VALUES(3,'<UserSettings>
   <ActiveStaff>
    <int>2063</int>
    <int>2062</int>
    <int>5</int>
    <int>10</int>
    <int>2064</int>
   </ActiveStaff>
</UserSettings>');
GO
SELECT Staff.[int].value('(./text())[1]','int') AS [int]
FROM #YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY YT.Settings.nodes('/UserSettings/ActiveStaff/int') Staff([int]);
GO
DROP TABLE #YourTable;
```